# Unable to import new hardware profiles into android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, google-glass, google-glass-camera

Since I do not have a google glass device. I want to create an emulator in android studio with hardware profiles but I am unable to import a new hardware profile into android studio device manager. I am trying to import the google glass enterprise edition 2 hardware profile we can download it [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/glass-enterprise-samples/blob/master/HardwareProfile/glass_ee2_hardware_profile.xml). After I click the selected file the whole application just freezes and I need to force exit it.

Added the image below for what happens after selecting the required file. Unable to move forward from this. All pre-installed emulators are working fine.

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is a bug of android studio, update it if possible, sometimes nothing happens but the profile is still being created, try to scroll the phones profile (it should be there). If you stil cannot import it just create a new profile with api level 27 no google play service, 640x360 resolution and 3gb of ram

Comment: Can you add a link to the referenced bug, would help others to track in future.